# socketIO-client can't connect to server

Tags: python, socket.io

I'm currently trying to connect to the socketIO server like in this JavaScript:

```
var socket = io('https://beta.glws.org')
```

This is the Python part which isn't working:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace

s = SocketIO('https://beta.glws.org', 80,
             verify=False,
             headers={'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'BtvJh6zvB4ILSo0sqIOntQ=='},
             cookies={'io': 'SCdIBbDOGDXhUBOZAkhM',
                      'gat': '1',
                      'ga': 'GA1.2.1442748168.1463601401'
                      },
             )
```

The cookies and headers are dumped from debug from the working site, but the result is the same as without them.

Result with logging on debug level:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): beta.glws.org
WARNING:root:beta.glws.org:80/socket.io [waiting for connection] [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (2): beta.glws.org
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (3): beta.glws.org
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (4): beta.glws.org
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (5): beta.glws.org
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (6): beta.glws.org
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (7): beta.glws.org
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it starting so many new https connections?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've established a connection with socketIO so I would fix that before worrying about the cookies and headers. Do you agree? I see Python repeatedly trying to connect but not being able to.

Comment: I'm using the example code like in [usage examples of the developer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client), but even with all of the examples there, it's repeating the same new https connection everytime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is you are specifying an https address when using port 80. Port 80 is for http and port 443 is for https.

Here is part of the line of code you should change.

```
'https://beta.glws.org', 80,
```

**You can either use the http protocol for the address and port 80 or you can change the port to 443 and leave the address the same.**

Comment: works thank you, I tried it before but without logging on debug level, so I didn't receive the HTTP/1.1" 400 None message which is apparently based on the protocol version, but it can establish the connection now